# POJO arraylist to String

Tags: android, retrofit, pojo

I'm using retrofit 2 and i defined some POJO to be able to parse my response from ws

```
public class mPojo
{
    public List<mPojo2> field;
}
```

How can i get the field as a string ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer that fits my needs:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
String json = gson.toJson(mPojo.field.get(i));
```